# Where is the coding for controller in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I mean I have created Backbone.View.Extend and Backbone.Model.Extend.
But I havent done the coding for Backbone.Controller.Extend
So where exactly does the code for controller come from?

Comment: Have you even read the Backbone documentation? There is no such thing as Backbone.Controller.

Comment: I know which is why I am wondering how the controller logic comes into the mvc pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How Backbone is different from traditional concept of Model-View-Controller:

> Different implementations of the Model-View-Controller pattern tend to
> disagree about the definition of a controller. If it helps any, in
> Backbone, the View class can also be thought of as a kind of
> controller, dispatching events that originate from the UI, with the
> HTML template serving as the true view. We call it a View because it
> represents a logical chunk of UI, responsible for the contents of a
> single DOM element.
>
> Comparing the overall structure of Backbone to a server-side MVC
> framework like Rails, the pieces line up like so:
>
> **Backbone.Model** – Like a Rails model minus the class methods. Wraps a
> row of data in business logic.
>
> **Backbone.Collection** – A group of models on the client-side, with sorting/filtering/aggregation logic.
>
> **Backbone.Router** – Rails routes.rb + Rails controller actions. Maps
> URLs to functions.
>
> **Backbone.View** – A logical, re-usable piece of UI.
> Often, but not always, associated with a model. Client-side Templates
> – Rails .html.erb views, rendering a chunk of HTML.

[source](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-mvc)

So basically you could add your controller either in your routes or split it between Model and/or View. Backbone is pretty flexible in this regard and it's up to you have you want to structure your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the controller for Backbone.

http://chance-an.github.io/backbone-mvc